# On the login page button "register" don't work (1.5 Magento)

Tags: login, patches, magento-1.5

After applying security patches I'm receiving error on login page:

> Call to undefined method Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data::isContextCheckout() in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml on line 92

And login button doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check if the method exists? I viewed the file on a Magento 1.9 version and the method exists there. Are you sure you used the correct version of the patch?